# how to check Object Reference?

Tags: c#

I have like this entity,

```
public class Receiving{
  [Key]
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string shipperID {get; set;}

  [Foregign("shipperID")]
  public virtual Shipper shipper {get; set;}
}
```

the Shipper relationship could be **1:0 or 1:1**

and I got an error when the shipper is 0.

```
var result = from p in productRepository
             join o in receivingRepository
             on p.fk equals o.ID
             select new {
               test = o.shipper.name // if the shipper is nothing related then it occur an error.
             }
```

The error message say,
**"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

How can I check that in select {}?

I tried,

```
select new {
  test = o.shipper.name ?? ""
}
```

but it is not working.

Comment: That means a variable or a field (in which its type is a `Class`) is `null` and you're trying to access its member. Your exception should be a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `(o == null || o.shipper == null) ? "" : o.shipper.name`

Comment: You would get a null reference exception with 'o.shipper.name ?? ""' when either o OR o.shipper are null.

Comment: That code should be `(o == null || o.shipper == null)`, not `(o != null || o.shipper == null)`. This will result in a null reference exception every single time `o` is null...